# Inserting a row of data from ASP webpage to Access database with OleDB

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, parameters, oledb

I am trying to insert a row of data into my MS Access Database. When I debug this through VS it does not catch a problem, but isn't inserting rows. This query is turning out to not have inserted any rows. My date are strings, and formatted correctly. I am passing 18 values over in the parameter list, there has got to be an easier way to do this. Is there another way to use parameters for OleDb? I have posted below my methods. Could you see if my syntax is correct? It still won't work.

Here is where I pass the information:

```
rowsAdded = ((DataAccessLayer)Application["dbAccess"]).insert("Employees", txtLname.Text, txtFname.Text, txtTitle.Text, txtCourt.Text,
        txtAddress.Text, txtCity.Text, txtCountry.Text, txtHomePhone.Text, txtExtension.Text, int.Parse(txtReports.Text), txtPassword.Text,
        txtPostalCode.Text, txtNotes.Text, txtRegion.Text, txtHireDate.Text, txtBday.Text, upPhoto.FileName.ToString());
```

Here is where I query the db with this method

```
public int insert(string tablename, string lname, string fname, string title, string toc, string address, string city,
    string country, string phone, string ext, int report, string pass, string postal, string notes, string region, 
    string hire, string birth, string photo)
{
    string tblName = tablename;
    string last = lname;
    string first = fname;
    string tlt = title;
    string tOfc = toc;
    string addy = address;
    string town = city;
    string reg = country;
    string phum = phone;
    string exten = ext;
    int rep = report;
    string pas = pass;
    string pc = postal;
    string note = notes;
    string regions = region;
    string hD = hire;
    string bD = birth;
    string pho = photo; 
    int rows = 0;
    int ID = 0;
    string insertString = "INSERT INTO @tablename ([EmployeeID],[LastName],[FirstName],[Title],[TitleOfCourtesy],[Address],[City]," +
    "[Country],[HomePhone],[Extension],[ReportsTo],[Password],[PostalCode],[Notes],[Region], [HireDate],[BirthDate],[Photo]) VALUES (" + 
    ID + ", @lname, @fname, @title, @toc, @addy, @city, @country," +
    "@phone, @ext, @report, @pass,  @postal, @notes,@region, @hire, @birth, @photo)";
    string queryLast = "Select @@Identity";      
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        oleCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertString, conn);
        oleCommand.CommandText = queryLast;
        ID = (int)oleCommand.ExecuteScalar();

        oleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tablename", tblName);
        oleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", last);
        oleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", first);
        oleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", tlt);
        oleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toc", tOfc);
        oleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addy", addy);
        oleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", town);
        oleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", reg);
        oleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", phum);
        oleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ext", exten);
        oleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@report", rep);
        oleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pas);
        oleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@region", regions);
        oleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postal", pc);
        oleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", note);
        oleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hire", hD);
        oleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birth", bD);
        oleCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", pho);
        oleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        rows = (int)oleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        dbError = "Add Employee command Error: " + ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can say @tablename? I do not think you can.

Comment: what If I did "INSERT INTO " + tblName + "(... ? That wouldnt not work

Comment: table name cannot be parameterized

Comment: Yes it would.  + tablename +

Comment: Still does not work, I have even tried to hard code the table name

Comment: BTW are you inserting an ID into an autonumber field?

Comment: I see also that your names do not match, for example a parameter `@postal", postal`, but a string `pc = postal;`

Comment: Finally, your parameters are not in the same order as they occur in your insert string.

Comment: I am inserting a ID in a auto number, but I use `queryString` to get the last ID to make sure its the next number

Comment: If EmployeeID column is autoincremented - do not include it in the insert. And again - you need to get your steps straight: 1. create command with insertString, 2. specify parameters, 3. execute the insert, 4. assign queryLast to CommandText, 5. execute to get the last id.

Comment: ... And make sure everything is in the right order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you do not execute `oleCommand` with `CommandText` being `insertString`. All three executions are done with command text equal to `queryLast`.

The fact that you passed `insertString` to `OleDbCommand` constructor does not mean that it somehow will be remembered after you assign

```
oleCommand.CommandText = queryLast;
```

On this assignment `oleCommand` forgets about `insertString` and will only execute what is in its `CommandText` until you assign something else.

Another thing: executing `insertString` will likely throw exception because sql parameterization does not support table names specified as parameters, if I am not mistaken.

If EmployeeID column is autoincremented - do not include it in the insert. And again - you need to get your steps straight:

1. create command with insertString,
2. specify parameters,
3. execute the insert,
4. assign queryLast to CommandText,
5. execute to get the last id.

Comment: I have just tried to add `oleCommand.CommandText = insertString` but it still did not return any rows. My insertString is instantiated when I call my `oleCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertString, conn);`, and `queryString` is a add on to the `oleCommand`

Comment: I see, I can put my `ExecuteNonQuery` before the CommandText and LOL: The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add.  Try inserting or pasting less data. Probably the reason i included ID.

Comment: Will the ID used then if i exclude the auto increment number?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. For autoincremented fields you   include neither their names nor values in the INSERT sql statement.